# Crear hash personalizado de 5 caracteres para una cadena de 90 en php o javascript

Tags: javascript, php, hash, cifrado

Quiero convertir una cadena de unos 90 caracteres (es un código único muy largo que se genera en la URL) en una de 5 caracteres exactamente que el usuario pueda comunicar por teléfono para identificar de dónde procede la llamada.

Ejemplo:
`dominio.com/?id=adlasjdasd7123_sdnasdoiasdasdasdasdasdasdasdas-R1`

Y ese id transformarlo en una cadena de 5 caracteres (0-9 y A-Z), como "1AR25". Con esa longitud, habría unos 60 millones de posibles combinaciones, por lo que el margen de error (varios id que tengan la misma codificación) sería muy pequeño y asumible.

Serviría en php o javascript. La idea es ver cómo se construye una función de este tipo personalizada.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas! No es nada claro el criterio de transformación

Comment: podes usar [CRC32](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.crc32.php) o algún otro [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.hash.php) y al resultado q probablemente estará en base16, [convertirlo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base-convert.php) a [base36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) (0-9,A-Z)

Comment: Yo creo que es seguro cortar un hash como Sha o md5, el problema es el que ya estás dispuesto a asumir, que es el de las colisiones.